# How to introduce a cat to a new cat?

Tags: cats, behavior, introducing-pets

I live in a small room and believe me when I say it is really impossible to separate the two (I live in a poor house, there is not much space). How do I go about doing it? My old cat generally have this harsh attitude towards people and other cats. And there is a new cat coming in a few hours. Should I separate their food and get them a separate litter boxes? What else should I keep in mind if separating them in a few days is impossible?

**Update:** Hello everyone! I've read all ur responses. It's been 5 days since I made this post. Just a little update, I managed to make a small space for the new cat with all her needs: bed, food, toys, her litterbox (dw, they're further apart to where her food is). It's a difficult situation for me, her litterbox is literally beside where I sleep. But during those 5 days, I've exchanged their sheets to get them familiar with each others' scents, I've made them see each other between the door and get them distracted with toys. The hissing became less apparent. I wanted to keep on doing these for a few more days but due to my carelessness, yesterday, I forgot to close the door and my old cat came in. They started chasing after each other, but there was no hissing/growling. I still keep them separated, I don't think they're 'that' ready yet, especially my new cat. It is a bit stressful for me but I'm not giving up. The new cat was given to me, FYI. I don't plan on giving her back because of her history of being abused by her previous owners. I don't want to stress the cat as she had been rehomed many times. And we've become a bit comfortable with each other now.

Anyhoo, thank u for ur responses! :)

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! How will the cats live after introduction? Will this two cats only have one room to live? If this is the case, I am not sure, if a second cat in general is a good idea...

Comment: wellcome to pets,i am introducing a 4mo kitten to my 17yo female cat right now,i have introduced cats  to eachother many times and it is never the same,what you are about to do is very dangerous and it might very well end in tragedy but this depends on the cats.how well do you know your cat?is it possible to rehome the new cat if things go bad?

Comment: If there really is no way to separate the cats, then I don't think your home is an appropriate place to introduce cats to each other. Or at least, I have not heard of any way to successfully introduce cats without being able to separate them. It is even more worrisome when you say your current cat does not get along with other cats. I'm afraid they will end up fighting and getting hurt, and you will have no way to stop it.

Comment: If you only have one room, you should not have two cats. I moved my cats, who lived together for 5 years, into a studio apartment. But after one fight, they did not have enough space to separate, and their relationship was ruined. I had to give one of my cats to my mom. Each cat absolutely needs their own space, even if they get along. One room is not enough.

Comment: Thank you for the update. You could post it as answer itself. this would more fit to this site's style

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find space to give them while they acclimate to  each other. Hang in there, and I hope the best for your kitties!

Answer (score 3):

I wish i had a good answer to this question.

Yes you need to separate the food and water for each cat.

You will need to make elevated resting/hiding places for both cats.

About litterboxes you will need one for each cat plus one extra,you need to put them in places where your cats can see any dangers(Your other cat).

You will need to have the emergency phone number to your vet and the emergency number for yourself.

Introducing two cats to eachother is about as dangerous as if you introduce your new girlfriend/boyfriend to the girlfriend/boyfriend you are living with right now,and tell him/her that the new girlfriend/boyfriend are moving in with you.

I guess my answer is DO NOT DO IT unless you know your cat better than any girlfriend or boyfriend you have known.

i want you to know that the girlfriend/boyfriend metaphor https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor i use here is entirely true it is how cats see eachother as competitors.